# Why does this code round the final answer?

Tags: c

your program should ask the user to enter the price of one carton of juice as well as the number of cartons being purchased. Note that since juice is an ordinary grocery item, no sales tax is charged on it.

Then, determine the final cost of buying orange juice under the BOGO offer.

```
int main() {
  //variables
  int carton, total;
  float cost;

  printf("What is the cost of one container of OJ in dollars?\n");
  scanf("%4f", &cost);
  printf("How many containers are you buying?\n");
  scanf("%d", &carton);
  if (carton % 2 == 0) {
    total = (carton / 2) * cost;
  } else {
    total = (carton % 2) * cost + (carton - 1 / 2) * cost;
  }

  //output
  printf("The total cost is $%d", total);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `1/2` is 0 in integer arithmetic. Convert all units to float.

Comment: total should be a float shouldn't it?

Comment: If I convert carton into float, it won't do carton % 2 == 0 if commnad

Comment: **DO NOT USE FLOATS** for financial transactions. Floats don't behave the way humans expect numbers to behave - they behave the way computer scientists/engineers expect an approximate algorithm to represent numbers to be acceptable. It is generally not **legally** acceptable in a lot of countries for you to calculate money the way float works. Instead use **int** but internally represent your currency as cents (or even 0.01 cent as required by law in your country). Add a decimal point to the value manually when displaying but internally store everything as int

Answer (score 0):

You just typecast the carton to float before dividing it. In this way you can also use  modulus(%) operator with it as it is actually a integer and you also divide it by 2 by typecasting it to float

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want your `total` to be a float number and not 'rounded' because you are casting it to an `int`, then you must declare it as a `float`.
Also you have some more calculations in the code that since you are using integers, you are getting answers that you are not expecting. (e.g.`carton - 1/2)`. I would highly recommend you to change all 3 of you variables to floats.

Secondly, in your last line you wrote:

```c
printf("The total cost is $%d", total);
```

- `%d` is used for integers
- `%f` is used for floats

When you do `%d` to floats you are casting it. Meaning that it's the same as doing `(int)total` and since integers are only whole numbers, your `total` will also be a whole number.

So long story short.. If you want `total` to not be 'rounded', use this:

```c
int main() {
//variables
float carton, cost, total;


printf("What is the cost of one container of OJ in dollars?\n");
scanf("%4f", &cost);
printf("How many containers are you buying?\n");
scanf("%f", &carton);
if (carton % 2 == 0) {
    total = (carton/ 2)*cost;
}
else {
    total = (carton % 2)*cost + (carton - 1/ 2)*cost;
}

//output
printf("The total cost is $%f", total);

return 0;
```